# Strange inequality relating Binomial pmf and cdf

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, probability-distributions, inequalities, binomial-distribution

I'm encountering a strange inequality I need to prove, relating the Binomial pmf and cdf.

Suppose we have $n$ coin flips, and fix an arbitrary $k \le n/2$ heads. Suppose further that we have some small constant $\delta$ (say less than 1/3, though I suspect the result would be true for $\delta$ as big as 1/2).

Let $p_\textrm{big}$ and $p_\textrm{small}$ be probabilities such that

$$\Pr(\textrm{Bin}(n,p_\textrm{big}) \le k) = \delta = \Pr(\textrm{Bin}(n,p_\textrm{small}) \ge k)$$

Then trivially: $$p_\textrm{big} \ge k/n \ge p_\textrm{small}$$

My conjecture is that 
$$\Pr(\textrm{Bin}(n,p_\textrm{big}) = k-1) \le \Pr(\textrm{Bin}(n,p_\textrm{small}) = k-1)$$

$$\Pr(\textrm{Bin}(n,p_\textrm{big}) = k) \le \Pr(\textrm{Bin}(n,p_\textrm{small}) = k)$$

where this relies on the assumption $k \le n/2$. I only need the first inequality but I believe the second stronger conjecture to also be true.

Why I believe this is true:

1. the inequality is true for the "edge cases", for $k = 0$ and $k = 1$ and for $k = n/2$ (very simple to prove)
2. Matlab
3. (Jokingly as a reason) This is essentially logically equivalent to the result I actually want, and I of course believe in the result I want

I would welcome ideas on how to prove this in generality.